# After installing My SQL in machine, In App config of WPF application at run time LocalMySqlServer connection is added

Tags: mysql, sql-server, wpf, entity-framework

I am using WPF application connected to SQL Server Local DB using entity framework. During runtime, I am changing connection string value in app.config and saving it.

Everything was working before My SQL was installed. After installing MY SQL without any changes in code. On runtime, one more extra connection string is added "LocalMySqlServer". And due to it, the application is not connecting.

In below code, LocalMySqlServer was added automatically on changing and saving app config dynamically after installation of My Sql

```
  <connectionStrings>
<remove name="LocalMySqlServer" />
<add name="LocalMySqlServer" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Entity.DataEntityModel.csdl|res://*/Entity.DataEntityModel.ssdl|res://*/Entity.DataEntityModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;attachdbfilename=filelocation;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" />
<add name="DataEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Entity.DataEntityModel.csdl|res://*/Entity.DataEntityModel.ssdl|res://*/Entity.DataEntityModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;attachdbfilename=filelocation;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" />
```

Comment: Do you get an error?  You know those are both SQL Server connection strings, right?

Comment: @David - Actually problem here is DataEntities is the one which I have defined. What I do is at runtime I change the file path of database and save. On save LocalMySqlServer unwantedly is added in config. Note this doesn't happens when My SQL is not installed.